# (super noob question) .py module with sqlite3 dynamic write/read functions used in subprocess.Popen() and also used in main results in *nothing*

Tags: python, api, sqlite, subprocess

first, please excuse my terminology please, i am barely a year into programming. Thanks. I created dbworks.py file, where i wrote some casual sqlite3 database functions. I had idea that i would incorporate it into more .py files, each of these has to download json from different api, and return it to db, meanwhile different py app can use those data (calling also this base db module/file from main *.py) meanwhile downloading data continuounsly. Bad idea. No i didnt forget to commit to db.

So i used subprocess.Popen() for each of these, meanwhile also expecting from those (imported dbworks.py) functions to work in main file. my imported init_tables_start() in main worked, tables created. Subprocesses with same functions... Does nothing. Why can anyone explain please ?

i can see that db file has 28kb, has initiated tables. But when i print whole table from main i get []. I wouldn't be surprised if writing to them wouldn't work, since those db functions are called from modules launched with subprocess.Popen().

I tried to print(**name**) everywhere, but its all really in same folder. Can anyone help me please ? I didn't took it far yet with threading and multiprocessing and all of that, i just wished i could execute all of .py files i need from one main file, so i may have control over which one of them needs to be restarted.

I also added a second table "semaphore" where each row is read by a dedicated instance (.py file that downloads), and updates data if they are allowed, because of this i think it should work without much connections/relations between those modules/instances that i need to run at once.

Thank you.

instance_manager.py code:

```
import subprocess
import sys
from dbworks import * 
import time

init_tables_start()  # <- from dbworks.py , works
read_from_db()       # <- from dbworks.py , prints []

data_getter_1=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, './data_getter.py'])
price_getter=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, './price_getter.py']) #<- in both i use dbworks.py, they did throw errors, fixed them, doesnt write to db

s = int(round(time.time()))

while int(round(time.time())) != s+10:
    print(str(get_value_sum())) #<- also from dbworks.py, prints 0 (works)
    time.sleep(0.32)

read_from_db() # prints []

data_getter_1.kill()
price_getter.kill()
```

Comment: Why are you using subprocess to call Python code from other Python code, instead of just importing and executing the functions?

Comment: @NickBailey it wouldn't continue from import , i tried it now also with if __name__=="__main__"

Comment: As is, your question isn't very clear what you're doing.  What is the return from data_getter.py and price_getter.py?  What do you mean "it wouldn't continue from import"?  There's not enough code to get an understand of what's going on.  How did you import before?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to put to logic of your other modules into functions so it can be run from another module. Using subprocess here is the wrong approach.